# File copied to folder unable to be read by folder owner

Tags: permissions, files, directory, ftp

I have an SFTP server that I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.  It was previously running 18.04.

The server is used to move files between a Windows computer and the FTP users.  An FTP user may upload a file to their folder on the SFTP server, and a task on the Windows computer will access the file for processing.  Alternatively, a task on the Windows computer will copy a file to one of the FTP user's folders.  That user will then connect over FTP, and download the file.

I add users to the SFTP server using these commands;

```
#adduser username    
#usermod -G sftp_users username    
#chown root:root  /home/username    
#chmod 755 /home/username    
#cd /home/username
#mkdir upload download    
#chown username:sftp_users *
```

On 18.04, the above commands configured users properly, with full rights to the folders in their respective /home folders.

After the upgrade to 20.04, the above commands do not give the same result.  Specifically, after the user is configured, if I copy a file from the Windows computer to a newly created user's "download" folder, when they then connect to the SFTP server via FTP, they can see the file in the "download" folder, but they cannot download the file to their computer.  The FTP client displays a permissions error (Permission denied. Error code: 3 Error message from server: Permission denied).

Any suggestions for addressing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `chown root:root  /home/username`  why? I would expect `chown $USER:$USER  /home/$USER` and `chmod 755 /home/username` I would expect `chmod 750 /home/$USER` Or if you have lots of users change the group to a common group something like `sftpusers` ... `chown $USER:sftpusers  /home/$USER`

Comment: Rinzwind, thanks for your insights.  As to the "why" of the commands, I do not know.  These commands were put together by a long-gone, former employee.  On 20.04, I have not figured out why the commands that did work on 18.04 do not work now.  I tried your recommendations, but still do not achieve the desired result, the inheritance of folder permissions by files copied into the folder.  Thanks.

Comment: "if I copy a file from the Windows computer to a newly created user's "downloads"" Could you add an `ls -l` of downloads itself and the file?

Comment: To comments here?  Sure.

Comment: ls download -l returns "-rwxr-----+ 1 root root 0 Sep 29 09:31 aztest.txt".  ls aztest.txt returns "-rwxr-----+ 1 root root 0 Sep 29 09:31 aztest.txt".  ls -al of the user's home folder returns "drwxrwx---+  2 azftpuser6 sftp_users 4096 Sep 29 09:32 download".

Comment: I looked into the UMASK command, but that appears to only apply to users connecting to the server via SFTP, and not to files copied from a Windows system, either manually, or by a task.  This issue, along with a couple of undocumented changes to SFTP behavior is making me regret moving to 20.04.